# ENV variables when doing Rails commands (migration, others)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, fog

Using Carrierwave and fog and everything working fine with AWS but when I try and do a migration and some other rails commands I get:

```
lib/fog/core/service.rb:244:in validate_options: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key (ArgumentError)
```

This also happens with the Rails console. I think for some reason rails is not able to access my ENV variables for some reason? But it works when running as part of a Rails server...

Any thoughts on why? aws key defined as below:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  config.fog_provider = 'fog/aws'
  config.fog_credentials = {

    provider: 'AWS',
    aws_access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'],
    aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET'],
    region: 'eu-west-2'
  }
  config.fog_directory = 'images' # bucket name


  config.cache_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads" # To let CarrierWave work on heroku
end
```

Comment: How are you referring to your env variables in the code? Can we see where you assign the aws_access_key?

Comment: added above... and then the actual variables are in my .bashrc

Comment: If anyone has any idea that would be amazing, I had to delete my carrierwave.rb which worked but is far from ideal...

Comment: I can tell you how to work around it but can't fix your issue..

Comment: How are your environment variables defined? Are they set in the shell you are running the migrations from? Or do you use the `dotenv` gem to load them from a file? ...

Comment: hey igneus sorry for the delay replying, didn't see your comment - my ENV variables are set in the shell. Still having this problem, will dotenv fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the above question but as OP has asked again for any advice..

Stop using ENV variables in development. Create a secrets.yml file, and you'll be able to access these values in your project. Make sure you add this to your .gitignore file as committing this is obviously not a good idea.

A very brief, succinct runthrough of how to use secrets:

https://richonrails.com/articles/the-rails-4-1-secrets-yml-file

Comment: but... if I understand, you still use the ENV variables in your secrets.yml, right? I researched this as a solution, but didn't think it would make any difference.. and I don't understand why it's better...?

Comment: You can call the secret values as they're assigned when you start the application. If you have a key there called 'aws_access_key' then Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key will return the value associated

Comment: If you want to quickly test, make a secrets.yml file with just one value, open up rails c, and try to access it. If it works there, it will work in development when running the server

Comment: Just re read your comment - no you don't use ENV variables in the secrets file